# all goroutines are asleep - deadlock, on a buffered channel, do not understand why

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I want to only create certain number of go routines, say 5, but I can receive variable number of jobs.

Here is my code that attempts to do it and the test is below it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func doWork(size int, capacity int) int {
    start := time.Now()
    jobs := make(chan *Job, capacity)
    results := make(chan *Job, capacity)
    sem := make(chan struct{}, capacity)
    go chanWorker(jobs, results, sem)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        jobs <- &Job{id: i}
    }
    close(jobs)
    successCount := 0
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        item := <-results
        if item.result {
            successCount++
        }
        fmt.Printf("Job %d completed %v\n", item.id, item.result)
    }
    close(results)
    close(sem)
    fmt.Printf("Time taken to execute %d jobs with %d capacity = %v\n", size, capacity, time.Since(start))
    return successCount
}

func chanWorker(jobs <-chan *Job, results chan<- *Job, sem chan struct{}) {

    for item := range jobs {
        it := item
        sem <- struct{}{}
        fmt.Printf("Job %d started\n", it.id)
        go func() {
            timeOutCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 300*time.Millisecond)
            defer cancel()
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(it.id) * 100 * time.Millisecond)
            select {
            case <-timeOutCtx.Done():
                fmt.Printf("Job %d timed out\n", it.id)
                it.result = false
                results <- it
                <-sem
                return
            default:
                fmt.Printf("Total number of routines %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())
                it.result = true
                results <- it
                <-sem
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

The test for this

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func Test_doWork(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        size     int
        capacity int
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want int
    }{
        {
            name: "jobs 10 capacity 5",
            args: args{
                size:     10,
                capacity: 5,
            },
            want: 3,
        },
        {
            name: "jobs 100 capacity 5",
            args: args{
                size:     100,
                capacity: 5,
            },
            want: 3,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := doWork(tt.args.size, tt.args.capacity); got < tt.want {
                t.Errorf("doWork() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The test `jobs 10 capacity 5` works, but `jobs 100 capacity 5` fails.

If I make capacity 50 for 100 jobs, it works, doesn't work for 30 and cannot understand the behavior.

Here is how I understood of channels and expected it tow work.

A buffered channel will block if its full, until there is some free capacity available. I expected that as soon as the jobs channel is full, it will block until chanWorker frees some of it. The chanWorker itself receives a capacity and makes use of empty struct to ensure no more than 5 worker is created.

Why should I ever get an error
`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the main goroutine does not receive values from `results` until all jobs are sent to `jobs`, the workers block on send to `results`.  The main goroutine blocks sending to `jobs` because the works are blocked.  Deadlock!

Fix by using goroutine to feed the work.

```
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        jobs <- &Job{id: i}
    }
    close(jobs)
}()
```

https://go.dev/play/p/WlbPRfxngRV